# Javascript code doesnt work in magento2 - How to optimize?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have following javascript, css and html code which does not seem to work in magento2. When I use a normal php file on my webserver and run the script below, it works perfectly. But in magento2 it doesnt..
Does someone know how to modify this script so it works also for magento2?
Im struggling and I did not find a solution yet ..

```
<style>#progress_bar{margin-top:15px}.progressbar.progressbar{background:#ffe8e8;border:0px solid whitesmoke;height:11px}.progressbar.progressbar div{background:#d95350;height:11px}.progressbar.progressbar.active div{-webkit-animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes;animation:2s linear 0s normal none infinite running progress-bar-stripes}.progress-striped.progressbar.progressbar div{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));background-size:40px 40px}.items-count{margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px}.count{color:#a94442;padding:1px}.items-count p{padding-bottom:5px;margin:0;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;text-align:center;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif}.progressbar{position:relative;display:block;background-color:#ca0000;border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:15px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)}.progressbar > div{background-color:#ca0000;width:0;margin-bottom:0;height:15px}.progressbar > div.less-than-ten{background-color:#ca0000 !important}#clock-ticker{display:block;margin-bottom:15px}#clock-ticker .block{position:relative;color:#000;font-weight:bold;float:left;text-align:center;width:25%}#clock-ticker .block .flip-top{width:88px;height:39px;line-height:40px;font-size:40px;text-align:center}#clock-ticker .block .label,span.flip-top{color:#000;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:14px;text-transform:uppercase;width:88px;line-height:25px;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif}</style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);}

        // Settings are here
        var total_items = 50;
        var d = new Date();
        var min_items_left = 12;
        var max_items_left = 20;
        var remaining_items = randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left, max_items_left);
        var min_of_remaining_items = 1;
        var decrease_after = 1.7;
        var decrease_after_first_item = 0.17;

        // Davy Jones' Locker
        (function($){$.fn.progressbar=function(){var a="<p>Hurry! Only <span class='count'>"+remaining_items+"</span> left in stock.</p>"+"<div class='progressbar'><div style='width:100%'></div></div>";this.addClass('items-count');this.html(a+this.html());updateMeter(this);var b=this;setTimeout(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after_first_item);setInterval(function(){remaining_items--;if(remaining_items<min_of_remaining_items){remaining_items=randomIntFromInterval(min_items_left,max_items_left)}$('.count').css('background-color','#CE0201');$('.count').css('color','#fff');setTimeout(function(){$('.count').css('background-color','#fff');$('.count').css('color','#CE0201')},1000*60*0.03);b.find(".count").text(remaining_items);updateMeter(b)},1000*60*decrease_after)};function updateMeter(a){var b=100*remaining_items/total_items;if(remaining_items<10){a.find('.progressbar div:first').addClass('less-than-ten')}a.find('.progressbar').addClass('active progress-striped');setTimeout(function(){myanimate(a.find('.progressbar div:first'),b);a.find('.progressbar').removeClass('active progress-striped')},1000)}}(jQuery));function myanimate(a,b){var c=0;var d=parseInt(a.closest('.progressbar').css('width'));var e=Math.floor(100*parseInt(a.css('width'))/d);if(e>b){c=e}function frame(){if(e>b){c--}else{c++}a.css('width',c+'%');if(c==b||c<=0||c>=100)clearInterval(f)}var f=setInterval(frame,40)} $(document).ready(function(){$("#progress_bar").progressbar();var tag="ctdn-12-12".match(/\d+/g);var hour=14;var theDaysBox=$("#numdays");var theHoursBox=$("#numhours");var theMinsBox=$("#nummins");var theSecsBox=$("#numsecs");var d=new Date();var n=d.getDay();var date=1;var gg=0;var hh=0;var ii=0;var nsec=0-d.getSeconds();if(nsec<0){nsec=60-d.getSeconds();gg=1}var nmin=0-d.getMinutes()-gg;if(nmin<0){nmin=60-d.getMinutes()-gg;hh=1}var nhrs=14-d.getHours()-hh;if(nhrs<0){nhrs=38-d.getHours()-hh;ii=1}var ndat=date-1;if(ndat<0){var mmon=d.getMonth();ndat=30+date-d.getDate()-ii}theSecsBox.html(nsec);theMinsBox.html(nmin);theHoursBox.html(nhrs);theDaysBox.html(ndat);var refreshId=setInterval(function(){var e=theSecsBox.text();var a=theMinsBox.text();var c=theHoursBox.text();var b=theDaysBox.text();if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0&&b==0){}else{if(e==0&&a==0&&c==0){theDaysBox.html(b-1);theHoursBox.html("23");theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0&&a==0){theHoursBox.html(c-1);theMinsBox.html("59");theSecsBox.html("59")}else{if(e==0){theMinsBox.html(a-1);theSecsBox.html("59")}else{theSecsBox.html(e-1)}}}}},1000);});</script>
        <div class="items-count" id="progress_bar"></div><div id="clock-ticker" class="clearfix"><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numdays">0</span><br><span class="label">Days</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numhours">1</span><br><span class="label">Hours</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="nummins">23</span><br><span class="label">Minutes</span></div><div class="block"><span class="flip-top" id="numsecs">36</span><br><span class="label">Seconds</span></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Check the console log it must be giving some error message

Comment: It gives alot of jquery errors, but I dont really know what they mean.. here is the site where I included the script https://thingbay.com/magnetic-phone-cable

Comment: Yea, still couldnt find a solution :/

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing </script> tag.  I'm not sure if that would cause your javascript to not run, but it certainly can't hurt to add in.  Also, I'm seeing a jQuery is not defined error on the line right below the Davy Jones' Locker comment.

Comment: Where is the missing javawcript tag? And where is a jquery not defined? What should i do?